# getting post comments for posts from facebook page

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get comments for posts from a fan page, from posts , when I try to get comments using http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer in the comment part I just get this result:

```
 'type': 'video', 
      'created_time': '2011-10-20T16:00:47+0000', 
      'updated_time': '2011-10-20T16:00:47+0000', 
      'likes': {
        'data': [
          {
            'name': 'Ignacio Lopez', 
            'id': '1368746018'
          }
        ], 
        'count': 12522
      }, 
      'comments': {
        'count': 495
      }
    }
```

but it could get the comments , I can just get the comment's counter , could you help me to figure out this problem ? , I wrote some program in PHP to get the post comments data, like this

Answer (score 0):

According to the Graph API [Video object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/video/) documentation there's a 'comments' connection on videos with the comments included; have you tried accessing `/{video id}/comments`?

Comment: Thank you guy ,
You know , when I tried to get comments for feeds or notes , using Graph API, in the result part we can see comments from others beside counter of comments , I don't know why , but I think this problem is surrounding posts ! ! BUT I'M GOING TO TEST /{VIDEO ID}/COMMENTS